# Xbox 360 start up problem

Tags: xbox-360

My Xbox 360 is fine and everything but whenever I start it up it starts up the game that is in the disc slot without me even logging in to Xbox live or anything as soon as I press the power button the game starts up.

Please Help

Comment: Is there any settings you may have enabled?

Comment: maybe I don't know

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled via the "Startup" option. The behavior you're describing is what happens when it is set to "Disc".

I found [an article on the topic](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/q-how-can-i-control-what-application-automatically-starts-when-i-turn-my-xbox-360), with pictures.

The setting is under Settings>System>Console>Startup and Shutdown>Startup.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]